# Prevent Entity Framework from inserting into base entity table

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have two tables in my database, T1 & T2. I have created corresponding entities in E1 & E2. Here E2 is derived from E1.

E1 is mapped to T1 table and E2 is mapped to T2 table. So my application reads E1 from T1 table. But, for any create/update/delete operation, E1 is cast to E2 and is supposed to be save into T2. But now when EF tries to save E2, it also tries to save E2.base (i.e E1) into the T1 table. In case of update this throws an exception (violation of PK constraint) since there is already a record with the entities identity in table T1.

The purpose of having table T2, is to have an approval stage, where once approved of the changes in E2~T2 the change shall be reflected in T1 table.

Also the purpose of deriving E2 from E1 is because, E1 provides the identities for both the tables T1 & T2 and therefore E2 only specifies what operation has been performed on E1 object.

If I'm not confusing enough, have a look at this:

```
T1 (int id, varchar(50) name)
T2 (int id, varchar(50) name, varchar(50) operation)

[Table("T1")]
class E1 { [Key]int id, string name}

[Table("T2")]
class E2 : E1 {string operation}
```

So my question is, when saving E2, how can I have Entity Framework save only into T2 and not into T1 ?

Comment: I know this doesn't quite answer your question, but one approach is to create two separated entities E1 and E2 and a base class EBase with the common fields. This way you avoid this problem and still take advantage of the benefits of Inheritance.

Comment: Where is code that you tried?